# handling a Large Number of Global Variables across several Functions

Tags: python, global-variables

I am writing a program which needs to operate on a number of common variables inside various functions. The number of variables can go up to 40.

one way of doing this is illustrated below where each variable is globally defined in each function This is ok when you are just handling 2 variables. At 40, this becomes tedious and I suspect rather inefficient.

```
import random


def rand():
    global x
    global y
    x=random.random()
    y=10*random.random()

def func1():
    global x
    global y
    x=x+1
    y=y+2
def func2():
    global x
    global y
    x=x+10
    y=y+20
rand()
print(x,y)
func1()
print(x,y)
func2()
print(x,y)
```

Another possible way is to create a list and pass this list to each function as needed.The drawback with this method is that you loose the convenience of having a meaningful name for each of your 40 variables.

Is there a convenient way of doing this efficiently?

Comment: If you want a list like container _and_ a name for each variable, you can use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using many global variables (which is bad practice) you could use a class.

```
import random

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        # This code is run when the object is created
        # You can remove it if you don't need it
        pass
    def rand(self):
        self.x = random.random()
        self.y = 10 * random.random()
    def func1(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 2
    def func2(self):
        self.x += 10
        self.y += 20

example = MyClass()
example.rand()
print(example.x, example.y)
example.func1()
print(example.x, example.y)
example.func2()
print(example.x, example.y)
```

To find out more about classes, research object oriented programming in python. I find [this](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) is quite a good introduction.

Comment: thank you both. I will research both methods.